# How can I write down paragraphs in HTML with Javascript without the use of getElementbyId?

Tags: javascript, html

So, i was working on this little formatting experiment with HTML, where you could create a paragraph via input and it would create an HTML paragraph on the screen. I did it by doing this.

HTML:

```
<button onclick="create_para()">Create Paragraph</button>
<p id="p1"></p>
```

Javascript:

```
function create_para(){
    var p = window.prompt("Enter paragraph text: ");
    document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = p;
}
```

And, it worked! The only problem is that I wanted it so you could click the button again and again and it would create new paragraphs without replacing the old one. The only way I thought I could do it would be by making a bunch of

tags with different classes, and having a bunch of functions, and a lot of buttons, but that's inefficient and too complicated.

So, I found out about `document.write()` and `document.writeln()`. So I used it in my code, but turns out it just deletes all other HTML code and just leaves it with the lines I wrote.

Therefore, is the a form of writing down paragraph lines without the use of ID's, or a form where it wouldn't delete all HTML code?

Thanks.

Comment: Sound like you want to [append to the element](https://clubmate.fi/append-and-prepend-elements-with-pure-javascript/) ?

Comment: Really your JS could be `.innerHTML+=p`

Comment: @Spectric that just adds words to the paragraph that was already made. I would like a separate entity, because I made the paragraphs draggable.

Comment: @jort57 Ah, OK.

Answer (score 5):

You can do something like:

```
function create_para(){
  var p = window.prompt("Enter paragraph text: ");
  var elem = document.createElement('p');
  elem.innerText = p;
  document.body.appendChild(elem)
}
```

EDIT: to add an id to each, you can add a global counter variable.

```
var i = 0;

function create_para(){
  var p = window.prompt("Enter paragraph text: ");
  var elem = document.createElement('p');
  elem.innerText = p;
  elem.id = '' + i;
  i++;
  document.body.appendChild(elem);
}
```

Comment: could you add an id to the new text that was made? I was using an ID to make the paragraph draggable.

Comment: @sonEtLumiere The dragging isn't working. I don't really know whats going on, so I'll give you the link: https://repl.it/@jort57/HTML-Test-1#script.js

Comment: dragElement(document.getElementById("mydiv"));

document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "header")

Those ids doesn't exist when using create_para(). "mydiv" is not an id specified anywhere, and neither is elmnt.id + "header". You want to use "mydivheader0", "mydivheader1", etc

Comment: @holtc So, what should I do? Could you clarify?

Comment: You need to use the correct ids when you call `document.getElementById`. If you pass an incorrect id, there won't be an element found.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a div container and then creates HTML Elements dinamically with your function, also you can assing an id to your new element, try this:

```js
let div = document.getElementById('container'); 

function create_para(){
    let p = document.createElement('p');
    let txt = window.prompt("Enter paragraph text: ");
    p.textContent = txt;
    p.id = 'your id';
    div.appendChild(p);
}
```

```html
<div id='container'></div>
```

Comment: fwiw, this will create elements with duplicate `id`s